# Golang http server app have many Socket (CLOSE_WAIT)

Tags: sockets, go, flooding

App can works few days. But in some moment, app has many socket with CLOSE_WAIT state, and cannot receive new client.

Maybe it is some kind of flooding(Example: Sync-flood)?

#### netstat -ant | grep CLOSE_WAIT | wc

#### 3258   19548  260640

3258 - socket in CLOSE_WAIT state

Update:

Code some handler:

```
 func GetScore(mongo *mgo.Session, redisConn redis.Conn, renderer handlers.Render) http.Handler {

         mutex := sync.Mutex{}

         return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

           id := bson.ObjectIdHex(r.FormValue("id"))
           banner := models.Banner{}
           err := mongo.DB("db").C("collection").FindId(id).One(&banner)
           if err != nil {
             log.Panicf("Banner selecting error: %s", err);
           }
           mutex.Lock();
           sports, _ := util.GetSports(redisConn)
           mutex.Unlock();
           sport, _ := sports.FindSport(banner.SportId)
           comp, err := sport.FindCompetition(banner.CompetitionId)
           if err != nil {
               comp, _ = sport.FindCompetition(0);
               log.Println("Competition not found");
           }
           game, err := comp.FindGame(banner.GameId)

           if err != nil {
           game, _ = comp.FindGame(0)
           }
           mutex.Lock();
           scores := util.GetScore(redisConn, game.ID)
           mutex.Unlock();
           game.Score1 = scores[0]
           game.Score2 = scores[1]
           w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;application/json;charset=utf-8")
           renderer.RenderJson(w, 200, &game)
       }



       func GetScore(redisConn redis.Conn, gameId int) ([]float32) {

         redisKey :=  fmt.Sprintf("game-%d", gameId);
         bBody, err := redis.Bytes(redisConn.Do("GET", redisKey))

         if err != nil || len(bBody) == 0 {
           response, err := http.DefaultClient.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", GameApi, gameId))

           if err != nil {
             log.Panicf("GetScore error: %s", err)
           }

           bBody, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body);
           redisConn.Send("SET", redisKey, bBody)
           redisConn.Send("EXPIRE", redisKey, 60 * 5)
           redisConn.Flush()
         }
         events := GameJson{};
         err = json.Unmarshal(bBody, &events)
         if err != nil {
           log.Panicf("GetScore json error: %s", err)
         }

         var event []struct {
           Name string `json:"name"`
           Price float32 `json:"price"`
}
         if len(events.AllEvents.P1XP2) != 0 {
           event = events.AllEvents.P1XP2[0].Events
         } else {
           event = events.AllEvents.Other[0].Events
         }

         return []float32{event[0].Price, event[1].Price}
       }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129810/discussion-on-question-by-s-denis-golang-http-server-app-have-many-socket-clos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CLOSE-WAIT means that TCP is waiting for the local application to close the socket, having already received a close from the peer.

> Maybe it is some kind of flooding(Example: Sync-flood)?

No. It is a bug in your code. You aren't closing a socket somewhere.

> The problem seems to be not in the code.

The problem is in your code.

> Code tested several times.

But not for this condition, or under the conditions that produce this problem.

> But yesterday I did not have this problem.

So yesterday those condtiions did not occur.

> (Code was not changed.)

So the bug has always been there.

Comment: I do not agree that the problem in the code. I close all that I open. I am sure.

Comment: I cannot close connection into http.Handler, app makes it for me. For everything else, I'm sure.

Comment: I will try to emulate the problem.Thanks

Comment: There is no other possibilty, whether you agree or not. That is the meaning of the state. The peer has closed: this end has not.

Comment: After code refactoring  (remove mutex), I do not see problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Emulation of situation:

When client timeout works. Socket on server will not closed 15 sec.
In my case, when app have many request, I have > 10k socket in CLOSE_WAIT STATE.

Emulation of mutex:

```
time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
```

Server:

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "time";

func main() {

   http.ListenAndServe(":81", http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        println("Sleep")
        time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
        println("After sleep");
   }));

}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://link").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        connection.getInputStream().read();
        System.out.println("Close");
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```